# UIImage Blur with CIContext in a background thread - Crash with EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading, uiimage, core-image

I'm trying to find a way to  blur  a UIImage on a background thread. I've tried multiple ways and the last time I asked here, I got the good advice to use **kCIContextUseSoftwareRenderer**. I was pretty sure that this would be the end of the crashes, as the main issue was that the GPU was trying to draw when the app was put in the background. This is not allowed, resulting in a crash.

This specific crash is gone now, but unfortunately the code below is still crashing for many of our users. We're also unable to reproduce the crash on any of our devices, we're getting crash-logs from Fabric (former Crashlytics).

I've marked the two lines on which we're receiving crash reports, both report EXC_BAD_ACCESS.

```
- (UIImage *)blurred:(float)inputRadius
{
// line of crash 1 
CIContext *context = [CIContext contextWithOptions: @{kCIContextUseSoftwareRenderer: @YES}];
CIImage *inputImage = [CIImage imageWithCGImage:self.CGImage];

CIFilter *filter = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIGaussianBlur"];
[filter setValue:inputImage forKey:kCIInputImageKey];
[filter setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:inputRadius] forKey:@"inputRadius"];
CIImage *result = [filter valueForKey:kCIOutputImageKey];

// line of crash 2
CGImageRef cgImage = [context createCGImage:result fromRect:[inputImage extent]];

UIImage *blurredImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:cgImage];

CFRelease(cgImage);
return blurredImage;
}
```

Here's a sample Stacktrace from a user:

```
Thread : Crashed: com.apple.root.background-qos
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x193933270 __pthread_kill + 8
1  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x1939d1170 pthread_kill + 112
2  libsystem_c.dylib              0x1938aab18 abort + 112
3  libsystem_malloc.dylib         0x19396e3e4 _nano_malloc_check_clear + 318
4  libsystem_malloc.dylib         0x19396d2f8 nano_free + 192
5  CoreFoundation                 0x18215e1d4 __CFDataDeallocate + 44
6  CoreFoundation                 0x1820a52b4 CFRelease + 328
7  OpenCL                         0x18d050eb8 clCreateKernelFromDAGAPPLE + 1328
8  CoreImage                      0x182837364 CI::CLDAGHelper::build_complete_kernel() + 36
9  CoreImage                      0x182813d20 CI::CLContext::render_sub_tree(CI::Node*, CI::Node*, int, CI::DestParams*) + 568
10 CoreImage                      0x1828148c0 CI::CLContext::render(CI::Node*) + 180
11 CoreImage                      0x1828247e0 CI::image_get_cgimage(CI::Context*, CI::Image*, CGRect, CGColorSpace*, CI::PixelFormat) + 1552
12 CoreImage                      0x1827ff384 -[CIContext createCGImage:fromRect:format:colorSpace:] + 648
13 Knuddels                       0x10003a768 -[UIImage(blur) blurred:] (UIImage+blur.m:35)
14 Knuddels                       0x100214094 __57-[ConversationMessagesViewController setBackgroundPhoto:]_block_invoke (ConversationMessagesViewController.m:571)
15 libdispatch.dylib              0x1937ed994 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 24
16 libdispatch.dylib              0x1937ed954 _dispatch_client_callout + 16
17 libdispatch.dylib              0x1937fa780 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 1848
18 libdispatch.dylib              0x1937fbc4c _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 108
19 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x1939cd22c _pthread_wqthread + 816
20 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x1939ccef0 start_wqthread + 4
```

Comment: you cant edit any UI element on background thread

Comment: I'm not editing, I'm just rendering a blur to a texture. Nothing of the visible UI is changed.